# Android SDK - alarm clock

Tags: android, sdk, android-alarms

In Android, how to turn on and turn off my alarm clock, using Android SDK ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Clock in the Menu of SDK...
Then,
on the left bottom,..there is a Alarm Symbol...click it..
It will display all the alarms already fixed and a link to fix a new alarm..
Select the Alarm that you want to reset...there is option very first to on/off your alarm...this is how it works...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can directly turn it off and on, but it sounds like you can cancel an alarm using an Intent. You can also set one. I assume it would just pop up the alarm dialog, which would allow the user to cancel it.

See [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) for relevant cancel and set methods.

Also, here is an [example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html) that walks through an alarm service, using the AlarmManager.